# Is there a plugin that comments by putting the comment symbol at the line beginning?

Tags: plugin

Consider the following snippet,

```python
def foo():
    do_something()
    do_something_else()
    print('Hello!')
    return 0
```

is there a plugin able to comment it as illustrated below

```python
def foo():
    do_something()
    do_something_else()
#   print('Hello!')
    return 0
```

instead of,

```python
def foo():
    do_something()
    do_something_else()
    # print('Hello!')
    return 0
```

Likewise, for LaTeX,

```latex
\begin{itemize}
    \item Accent
    \item Dialect
    \item Register
    \item Discourse analysis
    \item Language varieties
    \item Linguistic description
    \item Pragmatics
    \item Variation
\end{itemize}
```

```latex
\begin{itemize}
    \item Accent
    \item Dialect
    \item Register
%   \item Discourse analysis
    \item Language varieties
    \item Linguistic description
    \item Pragmatics
    \item Variation
\end{itemize}
```

and for C++,

```cpp
    strncpy (protobuf, protocol, PROTOBUFSIZE - 1);
    protobuf[PROTOBUFSIZE-1] = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < PROTOBUFSIZE && protobuf[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (isupper ((unsigned char)protobuf[i]))
            protobuf[i] = tolower ((unsigned char)protobuf[i]);
```

```cpp
    strncpy (protobuf, protocol, PROTOBUFSIZE - 1);
//  protobuf[PROTOBUFSIZE-1] = '\0';

    for (i = 0; i < PROTOBUFSIZE && protobuf[i] != '\0'; i++)
        if (isupper ((unsigned char)protobuf[i]))
            protobuf[i] = tolower ((unsigned char)protobuf[i]);
```

Comment: Vim-commentary can do it. I have provided a patch(like a year or smth ago) that adds an option for a filetype to add comment chars at column 1.

Comment: https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/commit/62b68aecec2de531bc3978bfb9c07d3b6759ce0e

Comment: @MaximKim Thank you! Would you turn your comments into an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use vim-commentary plugin, it has buffer-local variable `b:commentary_startofline` you can setup per filetype:

```
let b:commentary_startofline = 1
```

See patch https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/commit/62b68aecec2de531bc3978bfb9c07d3b6759ce0e